# How can I extrude all faces evenly and scale faces inwards separately?

Tags: extrude, scale

How can I extrude all of these faces on the rim of this cylinder, and then further be able to scale both edges of the newly formed face inwards?

I am trying to make a part of a wheel to a Tiger H1 Heavy Tank, similar to this part here: [image: Circled in red is the references wheel of another Tiger H1 Heavy Tank Model]

I have already figured out how to extrude all faces evenly, however I'm stuck on how to scale the edges for all of them inwards. The problem is, I can't simply just select all of the edges and scale them, because that turns out very wonky looking!

Here is what **I have as of now:**
[image: ex]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>i</kbd>  to inset, <kbd>i</kbd> to toggle individual, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to move along normal